# Firebase - Is everyone using the same app, or their own instance of the app?

Tags: firebase

I'm using Firebase for a single iOS app to consume data from a dataset, eventually I wish to make it so that a user can consume and write data to/from Firebase.

If 3 users are using the app, are they all using the same Firebase data instance?

> Tom, Max, Alex all see each others data, or are they only ever seeing
>   their own data?

That is, are they consuming/writing data to the same Firebase app?

I really don't want to do that, I'd like to keep each user's data separate and private (without logging in).

Is it possible to do this using Firebase?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If 3 users are using the app, are they all using the same Firebase data instance?

That is entire up to your application. Firebase is a hosted service and you choose how to implement it.

> Tom, Max, Alex all see each others data, or are they only ever seeing their own data?

Same as before: this depends on how you set the authorization rules for your database. This sort of access control is documented quite well in the [Firebase guide on security & rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/).

> I'd like to keep each user's data separate and private (without logging in).

You can use [Firebase anonymous authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/anonymous.html) to authenticate the users without requiring them to identify themselves.

In general, it sounds like you'd do well to spend some more time in the Firebase documentation. A few hours spent in the [Firebase programming guide for iOS](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/) will make the options a lot clearer and will prevent many problems down the line.